# How to style bootstrap 3 border between table head and body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing some basic styling of a table in bootstrap and turn the cell borders dark blue. Nothing fancy and a completely standard table but I cant for the life of me work out how to style the border between the table head and table body. I have tried everything to get this line to look the same as everything else.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to create a bootstrap table with borders on the cells that are not gray. My table is also responsive but that seems to make little difference

```
.table td, .table th {
    border: 1px solid #2980B9;
}

.table{
    border: 1px solid #2980B9;
}

  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>Table cell</th>
          <th>Table cell</th>
          <th>Table cell</th>
          <th>Table cell</th>
          <th>Table cell</th>
          <th>Table cell</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Should have said that if I run the table without the head I get a gray border at the top of the table which is very annoying

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use the selectors that bootstrap uses like so: http://jsfiddle.net/4tdS2

Your css could look something like this:

```
.table { border: 1px solid #2980B9; }
.table thead > tr > th { border-bottom: none; }
.table thead > tr > th, .table tbody > tr > th, .table tfoot > tr > th, .table thead > tr > td, .table tbody > tr > td, .table tfoot > tr > td { border: 1px solid #2980B9; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution. It did work. But in my table I had checkboxes. So if I add those including it in `<thead>`

```html
.table thead > tr > th {display:none;}
```

tag and click on checkbox, it would select all the below checkboxes. Giving it a feel of select all.
So instead I added

```
.table thead > tr > th {display:none;}
```

so that that table heading will not be visible at all.